# Migrate zookeeper data on Kubernetes to new storage

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper

I'm running Zookeeper on K8s with PVC based on gp2.
I want to recreate ZK cluster but with different PVC that is based on different StorageClass.

Solutions like zcopy can't really help here since this requires that I will have two clusters running but in my case only 1 should be running all the time.

The last option will be to have two clusters running for a while but it is less preferred.

Comment: What K8s version are you using? Its Cloud, Local env, Minikube, Kubeadm? Do you have configuration YAMLs?

Comment: Kubeadm (EC2) with default storageclass of GP2 and now I'm integrating Longhorn, so I want to move the data from EBS to my longhorn storage.

Answer (score 0):

look at Velero to back up and restore your Kubernetes cluster resources and persistent volumes.

refer the below link --> https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero